Is there a way to call for an anonymous interface with a parameter, as a method parameter itself?
Currently, I have this code working
public void method1(String a, Interf b) { 
    b.run(a);
}

public interface Interf {
    void run(String z);
}

And I call this by using lambda expression shorthand
method1("Hello World", ("interface string named z") -> {
    //do work with z, hence requiring an interface and not just a parameter
    System.out.println(z);
});

I would like to know whether there is a way to achieve this without creating a whole public interface (Interf) within the class that will only be used once for this very specific code.
I suspect there may be some type of anonymous implementation such as
public void method1 (String a, ? interface(String z) b) {
    b.run(a);
}


So you want Consumer<String>? There are a few of these interfaces in the standard library.

@Sweeper thanks so much this worked, the accept method from Consumer is almost perfect for me.

The other answer is, if none of the existing interface (see also here) fits, you can create a nested interface within the class using it. You can even declare this interface private. It still has to have a name though. Then, the method(s) using it, like method1 should not be public…
